# amCharts labels not visible

Tags: amcharts

Labels are not visible in amCharts

My code for creating the chart :

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "xy",
    "graphs": [
        {
            "title": "Si (100) Si2p",
            "type": "line",
            "lineAlpha": 1,
            "xField": "eV",
            "yField": "intensity2",
            "lineColor": '#FF0811'            
        }
    ],
    "dataProvider": chartData,
    "allLabels": peakInfo2
});
```

Please refer fiddle for full code

https://jsfiddle.net/gotquery/9rtx1qot/

I am unable to see the labels in the same. Inspect reveals that the labels are indeed placed but positioned way below the graph (I believe the transform property is setting the position wrongly.) Also there will be multiple graphs .. all of which are displayed properly but no labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`allLabels`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/Label) property is for placing arbitrary text labels in chart area. It's `x` and `y` properties are screen coordinates, that are in no way related to axis scale/values.

If you want to place labels at specific x/y value, you can use regular graphs for that. Just add those x/y + label to your chart data and create an additional graph that would display just the labels using [`labelText`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#labelText):

https://jsfiddle.net/9rtx1qot/2/

Comment: that worked but when i have multiple graphs and toggle the visibility using legend then it will still display the labels related to that graph . I want to add labels to certain points on a graph and there will be multiple graphs displayed together.

Comment: one way i managed to get it right was to manually edit the data to insert additional property of "label" to those specific datapoints in the chartData. now its all good. Thanks ....